# sass in rails 4 not reading

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is probably very simple. I'm not to rails.

I set up a new project and a controller called "say" and it's working fine. When I write plain css in app/assets/stylesheets/say.scss it reads fine.

However, when I write sass, I get an error message :

```
Invalid CSS after "    font": expected selector or at-rule, was ": $font-stack"
```

How do I compile sass - compass in rails 4 ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does your `Gemfile` contain an entry for `sass-rails` and is it installed (a la `bundle install`), and did you restart the server ?

Comment: What does the `$font-stack` variable hold? And is it in the same .scss file? Also don't forget to call `rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: Yes, my Gemfile contains an entry sass-rails and I installed gem install sass-rails. $font-stack contains : $font-stack: Helvetica, sans-serif and I use that in body font: $font-stack. When I run assets:precompile, I get an error saying : INFO -- : Writing /Library/WebServer/chir/public/assets/application-a(...)92.js.gz
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "    font": expected selector or at-rule, was ": $font-stack"
/Library/WebServer/chir/app/assets/stylesheets/say.scss:8

Comment: It looks like just some kind of syntax error/typo, could you please provide some code where the error is triggered?